# What is the best way to handle style tags when loading HTML with AJAX in IE 6 or 7?

Tags: html, css, ajax

Our AJAX framework works such that it sends back a snippet of HTML that might contain a  tag.  We then take that snippet of HTML and set it to be the innerHTML of an element.  In IE 6/7 it appears to ignore the  tags and so the returned HTML isn't styled properly.

I'm wondering if other people have run into similar problems, and if so, how they've dealt with them.  I know I could use a javascript library (we use YUI) to dynamically get external style sheets, so I could convert this to an external style sheet.  Just wondering if there are other ways to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Of course the best method is a pure DOM solution, ie use `document.createElement` to generate all the elements returned by the server.

However, there is (of course) an IE hack to work around some of the problems presented by `innertHTML`.  Instead of sticking the response straight into the DOM, first create an element, append its `innerHTML`, then attach it to the DOM.

```
function responseHandler(response) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innertHTML = response.responseText
    document.getElementById('ZE_ELEMENT').appendChild(div);
}
```

Comment: Definitely the most reliable way, especially when it comes to further manipulation. IE 6/7 don't do innerHTML on tables at all. Also, innertHTML? Is that what Yahoo uses?

Answer (score 0):

Inline style tags should be recognized. A styelsheet block will not, as they are loaded at the page's initial render time.

You can dynamically add classes you the existing stylesheet, but you'll have to parse your HTML fragment to grab what's there and do it in script.

see: [Totally Pwn CSS with Javascript](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Totally_Pwn_CSS_with_Javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can try jquery `empty().append()` instead of using `html()` or `innerHTML` for IE 6 to IE 8. It works for me loading full html document with inline styling. Here is the code sample.

```
var url = "inline.html";
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: function (html) {
        $('#content').empty();
        $('#content').append(html);
    },
    error: function () { return null; }
});
```

For more details check the blog link [Solution: Inline CSS issue and Ajax call with IE6 to IE8](http://ciintelligence.blogspot.com/2012/06/solution-inline-css-issue-and-ajax-call.html)